# Error loading CSV file into Neo4j enterprise edition :Illegal character in opaque part

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to load a CSV file into Neo4j Enterprise edition and I think I'm considering all the rules but I don't understand what is the error related to
this is the error :[image]

this is my csv file . I have entered my data in excel and then saved it as a CSV file :[image]

Comment: Please. share your CSV file.

Comment: I have just edited my post and shared the CSV file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy your CSV file to Neo4j Import Directory. Take a look in [Neo4j file locations docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/). For windows desktop installations this directory is `%APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition\import`.
2. Change your import path to `'file:///abc.csv'`
3. Try again.